# Identificador inválido durante select SQL - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Eu estou tentando buscar uma informação de acordo com a regra de negócio, que no caso é ID e CPF do Cliente de uma determinada Cidade e este cliente em questão não pode ter Debito ativo, porém das formas que estou tentando está retornando a mensagem de erro citada no título.

Banco de dados não é exatamente meu forte e por isso gostaria do auxilio de vocês para identificar onde estou errando e no porquê, vou postar dois selects, o primeiro funciona (porém trás a informação incompleta) e os outros dois são tentativas minhas de buscar o dado da forma que preciso.

Query que funciona:

```
SELECT CLIENTE.ID,CLIENTE.CPF 
FROM CLIENTE 
INNER JOIN CIDADE ON CIDADE.ID = CLIENTE.IDCIDADE 
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT * 
                  FROM LIGACAO 
                  WHERE CLIENTE.ID =  LIGACAO.IDCLIENTE) 
AND CLIENTE.CPF IS NOT NULL 
AND CIDADE.CIDADE = 'CIDADE1' 
AND ROWNUM = 1
```

Query que não funciona:

```
SELECT CLIENTE.ID,CLIENTE.CPF 
FROM CLIENTE 
INNER JOIN CIDADE ON CIDADE.ID = CLIENTE.IDCIDADE 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM LIGACAO 
                  WHERE CLIENTE.ID =  LIGACAO.IDCLIENTE) 
AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
            FROM DEBITO 
            WHERE LIGACAO.ID = DEBITO.IDLIGACAO 
            AND DEBITO.ATIVO = 'N') 
AND CLIENTE.CPF IS NOT NULL 
AND CIDADE.CIDADE = 'CIDADE1' 
AND ROWNUM = 1
```

A parte que dá falha é o LIGACAO.ID quando comparado a DEBITO.IDLIGACAO, esses campos são compatíveis, pois DEBITO.IDLIGACAO é alimentado justamente com LIGACAO.ID durante um cadastrado, portanto o erro provavelmente vem da minha comparação nesse trecho, já tentei acrescentar DEBITO no INNER JOIN, porém no ON justamente na parte de LIGACAO.ID = DEBITO.IDLIGACAO.

Esse ID da ligação é a PK de LIGACAO, logo ela existe, na tabela cidade o id é usado em comparação sem nenhum problema num caso muito parecido.

Desculpe se ficou muito extenso ou redundante, quis dar o máximo de informação possível e peço desculpa adiantado se faltou algo, não quis deixar tão extenso o post.

Comment: na condição WHERE LIGACAO.ID = DEBITO.IDLIGACAO se faz uma ligação com uma tabela não chamada no subselect , sem conhecer o modelo fica difícil opinar , como suas tabelas se relacionam ? DEBITO se liga a CLIENTE ?

Comment: A tabela LIGACAO não existe no SELECT mais externo. Na query que funcionou você utiliza uma tabela que consta do SELECT externo (CLIENTE).

Comment: Gente, muito obrigado.
A solução que encontrei foi encontrar o select anterior que já chamava a tabela LIGACAO e dentro dela coloquei o atributo LIGACAO.ID para compara o resultado do select do DEBITO

Comment: Ola @ThiagoTolentino, bem vindo ao SOpt, não altere o titulo para indicar que o problema foi solucionado, vejo que você achou uma solução e já publicou como resposta, mas tarde você poderá marca-la como resposta aceita. =D -- não esqueça de dar uma passada no [Tour] do site.

Comment: Entendi, pode deixar que dou uma olhada lá.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução que encontrei orientado pelos comentários que foram feitos foi:

```
SELECT CLIENTE.ID,CLIENTE.CPF FROM CLIENTE INNER JOIN CIDADE ON CIDADE.ID = CLIENTE.IDCIDADE WHERE 
NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM LIGACAO WHERE CLIENTE.ID =  LIGACAO.IDCLIENTE AND LIGACAO.id in(SELECT DEBITO.idLigacao from DEBITO where DEBITO.ATIVO ='S')) AND CLIENTE.CPF IS NOT NULL AND CIDADE.CIDADE = 'SAO DOMINGOS DO ARAGUAI' AND ROWNUM = 1
```

O problema era realmente esse, usar uma tabela sem chama-la explicitamente (no caso do CLIENTE.ID ele foi chamado de forma "implicita" dentro do select lá fora), resolvi isso usando a tabela LIGACAO onde ela já havia sido chamada.

Obrigado a todos, problema resolvido.